# Speaking during sex

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, dua

Is it allowed to talk with spouse during the sexual intercourse ? i have heard as its not good to talk. and is there any dua (invocation) to be recited before having intercourse every time and any specific time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding talking during sex, there is no clear ruling about it in islam that it is prohibited , haram or disliked. And you should know that in islam, Anything , that is explictly not considered haram/disliked, is halal or mubah in some cases as well.

Also, Allah says in Quran:

> Your wives are as a tilth unto you; so approach your tilth when or how
>   ye will; but do some good act for your souls beforehand; and fear God.
>   And know that ye are to meet Him (in the Hereafter), and give (these)
>   good tidings to those who believe.

So from islamic point of view, it is fine to talk ruling sex.

but from logical point of view, it is considered wrong to talk too much during sex, as it diverts your attention from pleasure to understanding the words. So you can talk , but better keep that talk specifically related to your enjoyment and your feelings during that pleasure.

One of the scholarly fatwa about same issue is here: http://islamqa.info/en/45597

And here is Dua to recite before intercourse:

> بِسْمِ اللهِ اللَّهُمَّ جَنِّبْنَا الشَّيْطَانَ ، وَجَنِّبِ
>   الشَّيْطَانَ مَا رَزَقْـتَنَا
>
> In the Name of Allah. O Allah, keep the shaytaan away from us and keep
>   the shaytaan away from what You have blessed us with.

Included a clear image of a dua,

[image]

And Allah knows the best.

Comment: is it possible to update the answer with including the english version of the dua, its too tiny and hard to perceive.

Comment: any best time to have sex according to islam? i have heard that thursday nights are good. but what about other days?

Comment: No, there is no fixed time in islam. but best time according to medical science is at time of Fajr, as at that time, man has high level of testosterone hormone (sex hormone), which give much more pleasure during sex to both. Also, dont eat anything , atleast 2 hours before sex. it will be helpful.